# Iterating over ExtendedDataModel in Java code

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have an ExtendedDataModel (RichFaces implementation of JSF DataModel) that I need some data from in the Java code of my controller. If It want to iterator over it and get each record could I do something like this (basically treating it like a Java collection)...

```
ExtendedDataModel <WorkerStatistics> data;
// call some backend code to intialize it here

for (WorkerStatistics workerStats : data)
    {
```

Or do I need to do something more fancy? Like the walk method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.ajax4jsf.model.ExtendedDataModel` from Richfaces class extends `javax.faces.model.DataModel`, which means you can iterate over it as you would do with the latter.

The method `walk()` is valid.

See documentation : http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.5.X/4.5.0.Final/javadoc/org/ajax4jsf/model/ExtendedDataModel.html

Comment: You're correct and although the methods haven't changed RichFaces 3.3 is fairly outdated, we're at 4.5 now.

Comment: @Makhiel Thanks for noticing that. Updated my answer with 4.5 documentation.

Comment: Thanks Thrax, it is very strange, when I used it with the for loop as I had in my code sample, my compiler did not complain but when I actually ran that code it never entered the code even though it had data as I can see the table with values on my JSF page. Is that the expected behavior?